# Ollydbg Comment Column - win32 api

Tags: winapi, debugging, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ollydbg

From what i see in the various videos/screenshots, whenever you load an executable, the win32 api calls are visible in the comment column in the main CPU window.

How can one achieve this? In my version, i don't see them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'analyzing' at the current location or the location where you expect to see comments. When analyzing self-modifying code like packers, decryptors etc, the contents of the CPU window might not have been 'analyzed' by Ollydbg, because they could just have been unpacked, or modified.

To analyze, right click at the desired location in CPU Window. **Select Analysis> Analyze Code.**

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it's always there but the default column size just hides it. Try increasing the column size of the disassembly window and you should see it.

Answer (score -1):

try 'Analyze This' Plugin for ollydbg

AnalyzeThis! is an OllyDbg plugin to allow OllyDbg's analysis function to operate outside of the marked code segment, by telling OllyDbg the current segment *is* the code segment.

Another way would be to switch to OllyDbg 2 -> MUCH better analysis; and more comments in Comment Column

PS: Analysis depends upon the executable type (c++, vb6, Delphi), so the Comment section may vary

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain how you can use that plugin to solve this particular problem. Consider expanding the answer until it is at least two paragraphs long (or one proper paragraph and some sample code).